# Problems faced trying to copy database found in the assets folder into the application's database folder

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

i'm currently working on a project but i'm kinda having problems trying to copy the database found in my assets folder into the application's database folder. Right now i cant even get it to copy into the application's folder. However, in one of my previous attempts, i managed to get it to copy into the application's database folder but it was found to be an empty database. I really cant seem to figure this out. Any suggestions?

Here the code used to copy the database:

```
package sirtat.individualProject.PublicTransportationTimeScheduler;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    //The Android's default system path of your application database.
    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/sirtat.individualProject.PublicTransportationTimeScheduler/databases/";

    private static String DB_NAME = "transportdb";

    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase; 

    private final Context myContext;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the application assets and resources.
     * @param context
     */
    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {

     super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.myContext = context;
    } 

  /**
     * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
     * */
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

     boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

     if(dbExist){
      //do nothing - database already exist
     }else{

      //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
               //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
         this.getReadableDatabase();

         try {

       copyDataBase();

      } catch (IOException e) {

          throw new Error("Error copying database");

         }
     }

    }

    /**
     * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
     * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
     */
    private boolean checkDataBase(){

     SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

     try{
      String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
      checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

     }catch(SQLiteException e){

      //database does't exist yet.

     }

     if(checkDB != null){

      checkDB.close();

     }

     return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    /**
     * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
     * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
     * This is done by transfering bytestream.
     * */
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

     //Open your local db as the input stream
     InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

     // Path to the just created empty db
     String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

     //Open the empty db as the output stream
     OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

     //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
     byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
     int length;
     while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
      myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
     }

     //Close the streams
     myOutput.flush();
     myOutput.close();
     myInput.close();

    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

     //Open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
     myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }

    @Override
 public synchronized void close() {

         if(myDataBase != null)
          myDataBase.close();

         super.close();

 }

 @Override
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

 }

 @Override
 public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

 }

        // Add your public helper methods to access and get content from the database.
       // You could return cursors by doing "return myDataBase.query(....)" so it'd be easy
       // to you to create adapters for your views.

}
```

Hope you guys can help me out.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109438/using-already-created-database-with-android/9109728#9109728

Answer (score 0):

/**
         * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
         * */

```
public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

 boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

 if(dbExist){
  //do nothing - database already exist
 }else{
```

//you have mentioned here if db is not in your database internal memory you are creating new 
*****check here

```
  //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
           //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
```

//block this line execute it once

//      this.getReadableDatabase();

```
     try {

   copyDataBase();

  } catch (IOException e) {

      throw new Error("Error copying database");

     }
 }
```

Comment: wait.. which one am i supposed to block? i dun relli get you. @@

Comment: @Ryuujin you need to block this line // this.getReadableDatabase();

Comment: i tried doing that.. but it still does not copy the database.. there is still nothing found in the application's database.

Comment: it's actually on an emulator.. @@

Comment: ya so what once your db is in your database folder it wont create again. so do adb uninstall sirtat.individualProject.PublicTransportationTimeScheduler